# How do you give a date interval with diffuse dates?

Tags: preposition, time

I'm interested in phrases such as

1. From 2002 till my pension in October 2016 I worked at the company X1 as Y1.

and

2. From 2017 till now I am working at the company X2 as Y2.

I'm interested in the correct translation of "From ... till ...".

Concerning 1, is it "Seit 2002 bis zum Renteneintritt in Oktober 2016 ..." or "Von 2002 bis zum Renteneintritt in Oktober 2016 ..."?  Concerning 2, is it "Seit September 2017 bis jetzt...". Or is it something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For 1
It is (almost) your second guess:

> Von 2002 bis zum Renteneintritt i**m** Oktober 2016

Note that it is i**m** Oktober, not i**n**.

For 2
It is either

> Seit September 2017

The "seit" already automatically includes the information that it is still lasting.
Alternatively you can say

> Von September 2017 bis jetzt

The former version is preferrable.

Answer (score 3):

*Von*, *seit* and *ab* can be used to denote the beginning of something.

The [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/von_aus_ab_durch_per_seitens) on *von*:

> 3. gibt einen zeitlichen Ausgangspunkt an

The [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/seit_seitdem) on *seit*:

> gibt den Zeitpunkt an, zu dem ein bestimmter Zustand, Vorgang eingetreten ist

The Duden on *ab*:

> 2. von … an

If you want to tell when it ended, you would usually use *von* with *bis* (*Von Montag bis Freitag.*). *Seit* is used when it's open ended and you maybe want to emphasize when it began. However, if it's open ended, you could also use *von* (*Von da an fragte ich regelmäßig auf German Stack Exchange.*). You can also change the above example to include *ab* (*Ab da fragte ich regelmäßig auf German Stack Exchange.*)

> From 2002 till my pension in October 2016 I worked at the company X1 as Y1.

*Von* 2002 bis zu meinem Renteneintritt / Pensionierung im Oktober 2016 ...

> From 2017 till now I am working at the company X2 as Y2.

*Von* 2017 bis jetzt ...

Again, with *bis*, *von* sounds more natural. However, saying

*Seit* 2017 arbeite ich ...

conveys the same meaning here.

Answer (score 1):

As a native german-speaker, I can't see a problem with your first translation. However, I wouldn't use "Seit" together with "Bis". I'm only a native speaker, not a professional, so I don't know if this is really gramatically wrong, but I'd recommend using "Von" in both cases.

Comment: Welcome on the site! Don't worry, native speaker posts are very worthy. Everybody can check the translation of a word anywhere, but questions like *how does it sound*, no one can answer that, only you.